# Get Collection of multiple Documents with its subcollection data with single fetch(Firestore)

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I have a user uid. User has multiple roles and each role mapped into different organizations and each organization has sports collections.

Now I have to check the user Roles and unique organization List then sports and finally send it to client

I'm facing a delay issue: some organizations come in and some aren't. Promise `await` is not working well or my code is wrong.

Get User details using id from (user Collection)

1. User Subcollection(Role by season) - Roles list with Organization_id as unique (multiple Organization)
2. Use of the Multiple organization List get all one by with collection.doc
3. After getting the organization and its child sports details(subcollection multiple)
4. After all the organization and its sports got you can return the response to the Client. The response must be role base organization

Example Code:

```
adminref.collection('/users').doc(uid).get().then(async userExist => {
                if (userExist.exists) {
                    //Roles Based Organizations                    
                    await adminref.collection('/users').doc(uid).collection('/roles_by_season').where('organization_id', '>', '').get().then(async roleOrg => {
                        const roleBasedOrgList: any = roleOrg.docs.map(doc => doc.get('organization_id'));
                        let roleBasedOrgUniqueList: any = [];
                        roleBasedOrgUniqueList = roleBasedOrgList.filter((elem: any, index: any, self: any) => {
                            return index === self.indexOf(elem);
                        }) // Unique Organization for the user

                        const roleBasedOrg: any = [];
                        if (roleBasedOrgUniqueList.length !== 0) {
                            roleBasedOrgUniqueList.forEach(async (orgInfo: any, orgIndex: any) => {
                                
                                await adminref.collection('/organization').doc(orgInfo).get().then(async organizationInfo => {
                                    const organizationDetail: any = organizationInfo.data();
                                    organizationDetail.sports = [];
                                    try {
                                        const sportsSnapshot = await adminref.collection('/organization').doc(orgInfo).collection('/sports').get()                                        
                                        organizationDetail.sports = sportsSnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
                                        if(organizationDetail.sports.length === 0) {
                                            organizationDetail.sports = [];
                                        }
                                    } catch (err) {
                                        console.log(err);
                                    }
                                    roleBasedOrg.push(organizationDetail);
                                    if (orgIndex === (roleBasedOrgUniqueList.length - 1)) {
                                        
                                        response.status(200).send({ status: true, message: 'Role Based Organization List Information', data: roleBasedOrg });
                                    }
                                }).catch(error => {
                                    console.log(error);
                                })
                            });
                        } else {
                            response.status(200).send({ status: true, message: 'There is no organization assigned to this User', 'data': roleBasedOrg });
                        }
                    }).catch(error => {
                        console.log(error);
                    })
                } else {
                    response.status(200).send({ status: false, message: 'No data available for this Uid' });
                }
            }).catch(error => {
                response.status(200).send({ status: false, message: error.message });
                console.log(error);
            })
```

Example JSON:

```
{
    "status": true,
    "message": "Role Based Organization List Information",
    "data": [
        {
            
            "organization_id": "AFIEflH0XBiAEPZuBdoB",            
            "name": "Organization 1",            
            "sports": [
                {
                    "name": "Foot Ball",
                    "sport_id": "foot_ball",
                    "updated_uid": "",
                    "created_uid": "",
                    "created_datetime": "2019-09-11T04:00:00.000Z",
                    "updated_datetime": "2019-09-11T04:00:00.000Z"
                },
                {
                    "updated_uid": "",
                    "created_uid": "",
                    "created_datetime": "2019-09-11T04:00:00.000Z",
                    "updated_datetime": "2019-09-11T04:00:00.000Z",
                    "name": "Ice Hockey",
                    "sport_id": "ice_hockey"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            
            "name": "Minnesota Made",
            "organization_id": "etYHyjCu9R5boNq2Fc4p",
            "sports": [
                {
                    "sport_id": "ice_hockey",
                    "updated_uid": "",
                    "created_uid": "",
                    "created_datetime": "2019-09-11T04:00:00.000Z",
                    "updated_datetime": "2019-09-11T04:00:00.000Z",
                    "name": "Ice Hockey"
                },
                {
                    "sport_id": "lacrosse",
                    "updated_uid": "",
                    "created_uid": "",
                    "created_datetime": "2019-09-11T04:00:00.000Z",
                    "updated_datetime": "2019-09-11T04:00:00.000Z",
                    "name": "Lacrosse"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a better solution with the promise `async/await` for Cloud function Admin SDK?

Comment: "*I'm facing a delay issue. some organization comes and some aren't. promise await not working well or my code is wrong.*" - if your doesn't does do what you want, it's probably is wrong, as you say. Please edit the question to show the code, and also explain what's not working the way you expect.

Comment: Please share your code so we can understand more